# jQuery - having troubles creating animated loading bar, shrinking left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create something like a `loading bar` using `jquery`'s `animate` and a simple `for loop` combined with `setInterval` function. It seems to work, but not quite as I want. My goal is to stretch the bar all the way to the right, and the next iteration should shrink that bar from left to right, and then it goes again, expands to `width=100%` (left to right) and next iteration should shrink it, again left to right.
Right now, the bar stretches to `100%` and shrinks **right to left**, not left to right as I need. Could someone direct me to fixing this?

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1kyk15tf/).

CSS:

```
  #x {
    background-color: #076c4a;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2222;
    border-radius: 150px;
  }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var click = false;
  for (var loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) {
    var rotatorInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (click == false || click == undefined) {
        loop++;
        if (loop === 10) {
          loop = 0;
        }
        animateDiv(loop);
      } else {
        clearInterval(rotatorInterval);
      }
    }, 2500);
  }
});

function animateDiv(loop) {

  if (loop % 2 != 0) {
    $("#x").animate({
      left: "0",
      width: '100%'
    }, 1250);
  } else {
    $("#x").animate({
      right: "0",
      width: "0"
    }, 1250);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a few problems. Your `for` loop outside your `setInterval` is messing up your variable `loop` inside your `setInterval`. You just need a simple `var loop = 0;`.

You also aren't reseting your right and left properties each cycle, so they are stuck as `right: 0; left: 0;` forever. You should reset each one to `auto` when setting the other to `0`, and you should set them with `css()`, not `animate()`.

[Here's a fiddle that fixes these problems.](https://jsfiddle.net/9gbqrrbe/)

However, even that fix goes off the rails after about ten iterations in my browser, because the browser's computations cause the intervals to misalign.

I would recommend rewriting the loading bar with `requestAnimationFrame`  rather than `setInterval` and `animate()`. Every frame, check the time since the animation began, calculate what the bar's width and alignment should be, and set the element's style. You get much better performance and it's impossible for anything to fall out of line.

[Here's a fiddle for that.](https://jsfiddle.net/sy98wtx5/)